# Import 60mb XML file to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql, xml

I have a 60mb XML file that has a list of products, approx 8k of them.  I need to get all the products from this xml file to a SQL table.  The xml file has a static name so i know what to look for.  I guess i want to know about the process, what makes the most sense and least overhead.

How?What? is the best way to do this? 
When do i parse the xml, so i have SQL handle it, or some other method.  in the past i have used a parser in a stored proc, but the old xml files where smaller, like 1-5mb, im not sure if a 60mb xml file will work.

Thoughts, Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a SSIS package so that you can rerun it. Have SQL handle the parsing by including the schema within the xml file.

Answer (score 3):

It would probably be best to write a short program in a language that has both an XML parser and a DB interface. C#, Perl, Python, Java, whatever you know best.